# Black links on new duplicate banner are counter intuitive

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, hyperlinks, design

I noticed today on Ask Ubuntu we got a new banner for duplicate questions.

[image]

I think the wording is a lot better and the bigger banner will cause less [confusion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2790/question-is-duplicate-of-what-precisely).  However it took me a while to find where the link had gone too.

[image]

I finally realized the black title *was* the link.

I found this rather confusing and counter intuitive, especially when the other links on the site are different colors.

Is this a bug?  Or is there a reason for the black link?

Comment: It's a hidden feature :P

Comment: Addendum: the links turn in "unvisited" colour in case you've visited it. Very contradictionary with the rest of Ask Ubuntu hyperlink colours. I suggest to retag it with `bug`.

Comment: @gertvdijk done.

Comment: It's just the default css class applied to question anchors; I'll remove it tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question links in that duplicate banner should now be styled like other links in posts' bodies.

Comment: A similar issue has arisen, which could probably use a similar fix: [More black links on deleted question page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6261/more-black-links-on-deleted-question-page)